# Bitmap Null Exception

Tags: android, bitmap, nullpointerexception, bitmapfactory

```
Bitmap bmp, rotated;
InputStream stream = context.getContentResolver().openInputStream(uri);
bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(stream); // stream does not equal null

Matrix mat = new Matrix();
mat.postScale(0.5f, 0.5f);
mat.postRotate((float)rotation); 
// rotation calculated using ExifInterface orientation attr. for example: 90
rotated = Bitmap.createBitmap(bmp, 0, 0, bmp.getWidth(), bmp.getHeight(), mat, true);
```

With the above snippet, sometimes bmp == null and I get a NullPointerException @ Bitmap.createBitmap... I am getting the uri from the Camera activity.. the image definately is getting saved.

I would get an OutOfMemoryException if that was the issue right? Does anyone see anything wrong with this or a way to improve it?

Comment: Are you aware that the InputStream `stream` in line 2 is not the same as `is` used in line 3? If yes, please post the line that initializes `is` *(since the bitmap is decoded from there)*.

Comment: Your stream is called stream and your decode is taking a variable called is;

Comment: @alextsc: sorry, was a typo. thats how it really is (acctually there was no variable for stream before this post, i split it out for debugging). It doesn't happen every time. I would say every fourth time it cannot decode the stream.. Im testing on a Samsung Galaxy S II using the Camera intent to get the bitmap.

Comment: @TomFobear Ok. Given that `openInputStream()` only throws an exception and never returns null, the only source for `null` is `decodeStream()`. According to the docs this happens when the image could not be decoded. I don't see how you can fix that in your code. Most likely that means the camera activity is to blame somehow for bad encoding. Do you take the pictures via a `ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE` intent, or is this your own activity?

Comment: @alextsc Through ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE

Comment: @TomFobear Then I'd say install a few other (3rd party) camera apps, set them as default and see if the error persists. If it goes away, chances are that it's the camera apps fault. Otherwise I have no idea. Everything else seems correct to me.